# My tiled, metro style layout becomes disorganized when I zoom in and out

Tags: html, css

So I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WkQa.jpg) that turns into [this](http://i.imgur.com/X4YmmgO.png). All I want is that the layout be the same no matter how far you zoom in (or what your browser size is.

I house the html code inside <`section`> and they are all essentially this:

```
<div class='wrap'>
    <img class='tilesetsmall' src ='images/sample.jpg'>
  <div class='ontop'><p class='example-text'>Overlay Test text </p></div>
</div>
```

the css is:

```
.ontop{
    background-color: orange;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*top: 0;
    left: 0;*/
    display:none;
    opacity:0.8;
    margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;  
}
 .tilesetsmall{
    width:300px;
    height:350px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
     margin-left:10px;
  margin-right:10px;  

  }
.wrap{
  position: relative; 
  width:300px;
  height:350px; 
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;    
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

for the longer and big square tiles, I just change the widths and heights and create a new class, for example `.wraplong` is merely `.long` with more 310 more width.:

```
.wraplong{
  position:relative;
  width:610px;
  height:350px;
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

I then use the same html but with `.wraplong` instead of wrap. I do the same with `.tilesetsmall` and `.ontop`, again replacing as needed in html.

How do I make it so that the layout stays the same? I can make it be the same by letting `<body>` have a `max-width:1900px` but I don't think that's the right way to do it.

Comment: So is your question how to make it so that your boxes don't "stack" on top of one another when you resize the browser window? If so, then you can just wrap all of your `.wrap` and `.wraplong` boxes inside an outer container div. And then apply a fixed width to that container div. Something like `#wrapper{width: 980px}`, or whatever width is wide enough to fit your desired layout.

Comment: thank you! do you have any idea why I have to make the width like 1900px or they won't stay in the layout?

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing a working example. If you want you could put your html/css into something like [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/) and then send a link. But as an example, if your desired layout included a single row with three 610px wide `.wraplong` divs, then you'd need a wrapper div that was at least 1830px, plus the margin/padding.